# Artifactory won't download asm-analysis 3.2

Tags: repository, artifactory

There's a problem that I'm experiencing with Artifactory 2.6.1 (and 2.6.4; upgrading didn't help) that has me completely dumbfounded.

Basically, when starting a new project in Netbeans 7.1.2 or 7.2, it starts downloading a whole bunch of files from the Artifactory server. All of these work, except for ASM analysis 3.2.

Without going into detail of all the other things I've tried like zapping caches, I've tracked it down to the following: when Artifactory tries to download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/asm/asm-analysis/3.2/asm-analysis-3.2.pom, tcpdump/Wireshark shows that it never receives an "HTTP/1.0 200 OK"; it only receives the TCP ACK. From the same machine, from the command line with curl and the same headers (the only difference appears to be that curl adds an "Accept: */*" header), it works well.

The machine is behind a proxy that weeds out naughty content, which does have it idiosyncrasies, but the fact that the POM file can be downloaded via any other means without a problem seems to exclude the proxy as the source of the problem.

The Java version is 1.5.0, running on Centos 6.0 on a virtual server.

Would anybody have any idea of where to start looking?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to execute trace query against Artifactory. Run curl against the url you get 404 from with ?trace in the end, e.g.
http://artifactory.host/artifactory/repo/asm/asm-analysis/3.2/asm-analysis-3.2.pom?trace